# Console logging in xcode with phonegap 3.4

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I'm sorry in advance because I know this has been asked before, but I have absolutely no idea why this isn't working. I've included the debug console plugin:

```
$ cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.console
```

I did this prior to the ios build. I can see the plugin inside the xcode directory. I've console logged inside the deviceready function, after the deviceready function, nothing is working.

Do I need to add a feature tag to my config.xml? Inside of xcode it says that the CDVlogger is unversioned. Is this an issue?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. This is phonegap version 3.4.

Comment: do a "cordova prepare ios" after adding the plugin, it it still doesn't work remove the plugin, add it again and do another prepare

Answer (score 1):

```
Please remove the console plugin by below command(you can use any of one commands)
$ cordova plugin rm org.apache.cordova.console
$ cordova plugin remove org.apache.cordova.console 


than add them by this command
$ cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.console

and check into config.xml file it is generated 
 <feature name="Console">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVLogger" />
    </feature>
```